# DDD with webservices DTO as value object: how to handle them?

Tags: web-services, model, domain-driven-design, dto, value-objects

I have a "**MyUnits**" application that let's manage Units (like meters, kilograms, pounds, miles, km/h...). The model is complex, it supports unit compatibilities, operations, conversions, etc.

I have another application (**MyApp**) that will need to use "units", so I want to make it use my "Units" application.

What I thought is to have a "Units" service (webservice) `UnitService` that consumes and returns a Unit DTO `UnitDTO`.

In MyApp, I have this model:

```
Operand
    value: float
    unit: UnitDTO
OperationAdd
    operand1: Operand
    operand2: Operand
    execute()
```

**The problem**: in `OperationAdd.execute()`, I need to check that units are compatibles (for example).

So either:

- `UnitDTO` has a method that will call `UnitService::areCompatible`, but that is wrong! How a DTO (that should only contain data) knows UnitService which is a webservice! It shouldn't
- `OperationAdd.execute()` calls `UnitService::areCompatible`, but that is wrong! How OperationAdd (an entity) knows UnitService which is a webservice! It shouldn't
- or I have a `OperationService` that does the work (and that can call services) **but** my `Operation` entities would be like data containers, entities with no methods, and that's not really what DDD is about

I don't want anemic entities, but in the case where I have an entity that uses a service, how can I do?

And: am I wrong thinking that UnitDTO can be used as a VO?

Answer (score 0):

An Unit should "advertise" its compatibilities. I don't know if the language you're using supports generics but I would do it this way.

First of all, the UnitDto contains state for some Unit. Use UniDto to create the concrete Unit (which btw is a VO). Each Unit should know its compatibilities.UnitDTO should only be a DTO , create other VO that will do the work.

C#

```
public class UnitBase
{
    public virtual bool IsCompatible(UnitBase unit)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public interface ICompatible<T>
{
     bool IsCompatible(T unit);
}
public class UnitFeet {}
public class UnitMeter:UnitBase,ICompatible<UnitFeet>
{
    bool IsCompatible(UnitFeet unit) { return true;}
 }
 public override bool IsCompatible(UnitBase unit)
 {
    return IsCompatible((UnitFeet)unit);

 }
```

The compiler should chose the right overload depending on the compared unit. Also the ICompatbile interface can have conversion methods from one unit to another. But let's suppose you want things more abstract

```
public class OperandValue:ICompatbile<OperandValue>
{ 
     public decimal Value {get;set;}
     public UnitBase Unit {get;set;}
     public bool IsCompatbile(OperandValue other)
     {
        return Unit.IsCompatbile(other.Unit);
     }

     public static OperandValue FromDto(Operand data)
      {
         return new OperandValue(data.Value,UnitBase.FromDto(data.Unit));
       }
}

 OperandValue first=OperandValue.FromDto(operand1);
 OperandValue second=OperandValue.FromDto(operand2);

if (first.IsCompatbile(second)){
    OperationService.Add(first,second)
  }
```

So you don't need a UnitService::AreCompatbile method, just a LOT of polymorphism and careful object design.

Comment: I wasn't very clear but units are entities in my "Units" app: they are stored in database. There are conversion numbers between units (km, m, miles, foot, ...). So the webservice provides unit DTO to access units entities, so maybe this is wrong for me to use the DTO as a VO in another app...

Comment: It sounds confusing, but yes, you shouldn't use DTO as VO, they have different purposes